# Selecting <li> child node but not grandchildren with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have some lists set up like the following:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">link a</a>
        <ul>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">link b</a>
        <ul>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">link c</a>
        <ul>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to pull the text from each of the first anchors (link a, link b, link c), but am having some problems.

Most recently, I've tried:

```
var X = document.getElementById("menu");
var Y = X.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0; i < Y.length; i++) {
    var Z = Y[i].getElementsByTagName('A');
    console.log(Z[0].innerHTML);
}
```

but this jumps into the `<ul>`s within the `<li>`s.

What I need really is to be able to get the `<a>` reference to the top level `<li>`s and also be able to grab the text within the `<a>` of those `<li>`s.

Answer (score 4):

To get direct children of the `ul#menu` use [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) HTMLCollection:

```
var X = document.getElementById("menu").children;
```

Alternatively, you could select the same collection of `li` elements with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method using [direct children selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors):

```
var X = document.querySelectorAll("#menu > li");
```

Comment: why would my code not return back the first one but return back all the rest?   var children = document.querySelectorAll("#menu > li");
  for(var i=0; i < children.length; i++){
   console.log(children[i].firstChild.innerHTML);
  }

Comment: its coming back as undefined

Comment: @RON2015, please check example: http://jsfiddle.net/txmvshpa/1/ If i understand correctly - ''sub-link'' shouldn't be returned? The easiest way would be to add class to top level li's, and to target their class, if it is allowed.... :)

Comment: @nevermind  thank you but i do not want sub link returned, only link a, link b, link c

Comment: @RON2015 it's undefined because `firstChild` is a textNode (new line chracter or tab, space, etc.). You want `children[0].firstElementChild`. Or you can select `a` element all at once with `var a = document.querySelectorAll("#menu > li > a")`.

Comment: @dfsq thank you, and thank everyone else who helped with this.. I hope this works in IE7, im using menu.children; instead of querySelectorAll because i saw on that compatability page that its not supported in IE7.  will the way I am doing it work??

Comment: @RON2015: why not try it and find out?

Comment: @RON2015 Yes, for IE7 compatibility you should use `children`. It should work for you well.

Comment: It is working well, thank you for that, but there is another issue now... If you happen to see this comment, please take a look at the new question page I posted.  Thanks again.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463048/getcomputedstyle-substitue-currentstyle-ie8-7-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `document.querySelectorAll` for this. It is wide supported: http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

And it is easy to query like in css style. Hope it help. Here is the documentation of how to use it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Also can be interested in this for selecting single item: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

```
var childNodes = document.querySelectorAll("#menu > li");
```

Comment: Then check the answer of dfsq . Unfortunately do not have ie to test

Answer (score 0):

```
var X = document.getElementById("menu");
var Y = X.getElementsByTagName("li");



for (var i = 0; i < Y.length; i++) {
 if(Y[i].parentNode.getAttribute('id')=='menu') {


   var Z = Y[i].getElementsByTagName('a');
   console.log(Z[0].innerHTML);

   }




}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/txmvshpa/3/